# VS Code - run command from icon in activity bar

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is it possible to run a custom command from an icon in activity bar rather than showing a panel in primary sidebar?

I'm able to show an icon in the activity bar, and also I'm capable of executing my custom command from command palette.

But I can't merge those two.